# How to Get all Order using GraphQL in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, orders, magento2.4, rest-api, graphql

I want to get all Pending order Status Orders using GraphQL, Anyone can share a complete example or module. How to I'll do that ?

I have create Custom module Admin Grid, Now i want to display Only Pending Orders in that grid. So i want to get all those orders using GraphQL. So Kindly help me on this. How to I'll do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For Check What is GraphQL in Magento 2, Read Blog, [GraphQl in Magento 2](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/graphql-in-magento-2/)

Check the link, [Get List of Orders of Customer using GraphQl Magento 2 full module](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-get-list-of-customers-order-using-graphql-magento-2/)

For Get List of orders of Customer by customer id, You need to create a schema file for getting a response from Query.

In above you have declared schema file for getting multiple records of order for a specific customer.

```
type SalesOrder @doc(description: "Sales Order graphql gather Data of specific order information") {
    order_array: [String] @doc(description: "Array of order list.") }
```

In above **order_array** is used for getting an array of records but in your resolver, you made mistakes for multiple records.

In **$orderCollection[]** you need to pass array key for each record and you forgot to add that in your code.

You can try with,

```
foreach($orders as $k => $order) {
            $orderCollection['order_array'][$k] = [
                'increment_id' => $order->getIncrementId(),
                'grand_total' => $order->getGrandTotal(),
                'customer_id' => $order->getCustomerId(),
            ];
        }
```

Let me know if you have any query.